# Ruby meta programming, how can this code be cleaned up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have some code that is being repeated over and over, and it looks rather terrible. What's the best way to use Ruby's metaprogramming to clean this up?

A recurring theme I have is something like this:

```
class Object
  def some_logger
    @some_logger ||= Logger.new("log/some.log")
  end

  def some2_logger
    @some2_logger ||= Logger.new("log/some2.log")
  end
end
```

In theory, I just want to be able to call an arbitrary logger throughout my Rails app and have those logs go to a separate, easily identifiable file. So I can at random will call:

`some3_logger.info("Wooohooo!")` in a controller or model without having to go back to my initialization code and create it there.

Comment: Code review requests should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pass the logger name as a parameter:

```
module CustomLogger
    def custom_logger(name)
        @custom_loggers ||= {}
        @custom_loggers[name] ||= Logger.new("log/#{name}.log")
    end
end
```

Just include CustomLogger wherever you need and you can do:

```
custom_logger("some3").info("Wooohooo!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would not put this on Object. Putting methods on Object is just asking for trouble.

Maybe something like this would suit your needs:

```
class MyLogger
  def self.method_missing(method, *args)
    if method =~ /logger$/
      logger_name = method.to_s.split('_').first
      symbol = "@@#{logger_name}".to_sym
      unless class_variable_defined?(symbol)
        class_variable_set(symbol, Logger.new("log/#{logger_name}.log"))
      end
      class_variable_get(symbol)
    end
  end
end

MyLogger.some_logger.info('This is very information.')
MyLogger.test_logger.debug('This goes into a separate file and is for debugging only.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this in any classes that get the whimsical logger behavior:

```
module DynoLogger

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    if logger_method? method
      ivar = "@#{method}"
      base = method.to_s
      base[/_logger$/] = ""

      instance_variable_get(ivar) ||
        instance_variable_set(ivar, new_logger(base))
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method, include_private)
    super || logger_method?(method)
  end

  def logger_method?(method)
    !!(method =~ /_logger$/)
  end

  def new_logger(name)
    Logger.new "log/#{name}.log"
  end

end
```

Comment: Note that it's nice to override respond_to_missing? (or respond_to? if you're in ruby 1.8) if you're going to override method_missing? to implement methods on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with ruby-on-rails,  I assume you are in that environment, so it wouldn't be bad to follow its example of `Rails.logger.` to namespace the loggers... If the rails logger is not  good enough you could monkey patch that namesspace instead of Object.

Also, you could look at Notifications as a possible way to log things. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3